# Excluding a CDI Bean based on a PropertyFileConfig (DeltaSpike, WebSphere 8.5.5)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, deltaspike

I am trying to exclude a Bean implementation using the DeltaSpike 1.0 `@Exclude`-Annotation. The exclusion should be based on a property value like this:

```
@Exclude(onExpression = "providerimplementation!=mock")
```

I created a `PropertyFileConfig` returning my `.properties` file name to let DeltaSpike pick up the configured value and used this `@Exclude` in two different implementing beans, each of them being excluded like above.

The configuration is included in an EAR as a `.jar` file and both implementations sit in different `.jar` files inside the EAR.

I am trying to deploy the whole archive onto a WebSphere 8.5.5 Server and on startup I get a `javax.enterprise.inject.AmbiguousResolutionException` for the injection point.

It seems to me that the `PropertyFileConfig` is not picked up before the expression resolution, although I found references to this kind of pattern (http://deltaspike.apache.org/core.html#exclude and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-config/xsleMKST3rU), so I wonder what's wrong with my setup.

Comment: Is using a WAR an option?  We don't have great support for EARs currently in DeltaSpike, due to various classloader issues.

Comment: As far as I know WebSphere (at least the Full Profile) does not support deploying WAR-Files by themselves. We currently use a "skinny WAR" setup for the deployment, so each dependent JAR is placed directly inside the EAR. Could this setup be the problem? Normal injection works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First answer :*

Unfortunately, properties defined via the PropertyFileConfig facility can't be used with @Exclude.

That's because the extension [ConfigurationExtension](https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/core/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/deltaspike/core/impl/config/ConfigurationExtension.java) only registers PropertyFileConfig at the end of the container initialization (which is problably mandatory as PropertyFileConfig classes are used as CDI Beans)

Instead you have to use the default ConfigSource implementations :
http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/configuration.html#_configsources_provided_by_default
or create your own custom ConfigSource

In particular a quick workaround here, is to defined your property in the default property file : `META-INF/apache-deltaspike.properties`
instead of a custom property file

*Edit* :

In fact my previous answer is incomplete (at least with the last version of DeltaSpike (1.3.0 today)) :
the javadoc for PropertyFileConfig now documents this limitation AND shows another way to configure custom property files using the serviceloader facility :
http://deltaspike.apache.org/javadoc/1.3.0/org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/config/PropertyFileConfig.html